# next-auth signIn fail with oauth_get_access_token_error and callback_oauth_error errors when provider is Auth0

Tags: next.js, auth0, next-auth

On a NextJS app with next-auth library for authorisation via Auth0, I am getting errors during the authorisation flow:

```json
[next-auth][error][oauth_get_access_token_error] [
  {
    statusCode: 401,
    data: '{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}'
  },
  undefined,
  undefined
] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_get_access_token_error
[next-auth][error][oauth_get_access_token_error] [
  {
    statusCode: 401,
    data: '{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}'
  },
  undefined,
  'auth0',
  'HRLMyC9s88eIttwR'
] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_get_access_token_error
[next-auth][error][callback_oauth_error] {
  statusCode: 401,
  data: '{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Unauthorized"}'
} 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#callback_oauth_error
```

None of the referenced errors has any details.

The application settings in auth0 are really the base only the `Allowed Callback URLs` is set to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/auth0` as the auth0 login was complaining about it.

The next-auth configuration in `./api/auth/...[nextauth]` file is like:

```
...
    [
      NextAuthProviders.Auth0({
        clientId: process.env.NEXTAUTH_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        domain: process.env.NEXTAUTH_AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      })
   ],
   debug: true,
...
```

What could be the mis-configuration? Is is at all possible to run auth0 via next-auth provider on localhost?

Comment: You sure you have `NEXTAUTH_` prefix before each of the environment variables? Also that might be related to lack of specific TSL (Transport Layer Security) package on your machine.

Comment: I have tried that out WITHOUT any custom configuration using next-auth-example, and without setting up a custom server to run my next app with https and no local SSL configuration, still it works fine with Auth0.

Comment: I do have prefixes, the env variables are properly loaded. There are is not trace for any possible TLS errors. From Auth0 side, is there any specific for the callback URI or such?

Comment: I have set the exact same URL as you provide as callback URL inside Auth0 setting, and leave the  `Application Login URI` input blank.

Comment: is the issue resolved? I am stuck with it now.

Comment: Yep, The nextauth_url is a must to match the callback url configuration in the Auth0 application configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to change the The next-auth configuration filename from `...[nextauth]` to `[...nextauth]`, it should be like `./api/auth/[...nextauth]`, just hopping This being the issue.

If not, as I've mentioned in the comments:

> I have tried this out WITHOUT any custom configuration using
> [next-auth-example](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example), and without setting up a custom server to run my
> next app with https and no local SSL configuration, still it works
> fine with Auth0.

But I had problem at first, tried out:

- Enabled TLS 1.3 Support in windows
- Disabled QUIC Protocol on chrome
- Cleared my Web History/Cache

And then it starts to work.